# Apply properties to subclass of generic type

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HidingMyAppNameHereSoYouCantStealMyIdeas.Classes._Main
{
    public class Theme
    {
        private Color ForeColor;
        private Color BackColor;

        public Theme(Color fore, Color back)
        {
            ForeColor = fore; BackColor = back;
        }

        public void ApplyTo<T>() where T : Form
        {
            T.ForeColor = Color.Black;

        }

        public void ApplyTo(Control control)
        {
            control.ForeColor = ForeColor;
            control.BackColor = BackColor;
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm getting an error at `T` in `T.ForeColor = Color.Black;` saying:

> Error CS011: 'T' is a type parameter, which is not valid in the given
>   context

I'm assuming what I did wrong was try to access the property of a generic.

Anyways, I think it's clear what I'm trying to do here, since the `Form` when creating a Windows Forms app is generally a class rather than a variable like the controls for the Form app.

As much as I can probably find a way around this, I want to know if it's possible to access the properties of T (the subclass of Form I'm interested in) and change it so the code in `ApplyTo<T>() where T : Form` has no error, for learning purposes. If it's not possible, that's entirely fine too.

Comment: You can't access properties of classes - you can only access properties of objects of certain classes.

Comment: In what situation would you use `ApplyTo<T>()`? Seems like you'd only need `ApplyTo(Control)`.

Comment: @MetaColon Good point. In which case, silly mistake on my part.

Comment: @JohnWu I want to change the theme of the form itself. The form isn't a control though, and Form1 implements Form. I think I got confused there a bit.

Comment: A form *is* a control. Specifically, `System.Windows.Forms.Form` inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`. You just need the one method. You don't need generics at all.

Answer (score 4):

If you'd change the code from

```
public void ApplyTo<T>() where T : Form
{
    T.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

to

```
public void ApplyTo<T>(T form) where T : Form
{
    form.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

it should work, as you can't access the property of a class itself but only of the objects of the class.

However, you don't even seem to need a generic type here - you could simply use:

```
public void ApplyTo(Form form)
{
    form.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Comment: Since a form is a type of control, you could just call `ApplyTo(Control)` (defined lower down in the class). There is no apparent purpose to `ApplyTo<T>(form)`.

Comment: @JohnWu Okay. I didn't know the form was a control. My fault there too...

Comment: Also, all forms are derived from `Form` before being `Controls`. `public void ApplyTo(Form form) {...}` would do.